# Clerics and Spell Preparation

Tags: pathfinder-1e, cleric

How long does it take to prepare spells?  I see in one place in the book that spell preparation is supposed to take one hour, but I see in another that it can take 'as few as 15 minutes'.  Which is it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the **Core Rulebook** under the Cleric class in **Chapter 3**: Each cleric must choose a time when she must spend 1 hour each day in quiet contemplation or supplication to regain her daily allotment of spells. By daily allotment this refers to **all** their spells.

From the **Core Rulebook** under Divine spells in **Chapter 9**: When preparing spells for the day, a cleric can leave **some** of her spell slots open. Later during that day, she can repeat the preparation process as often as she likes. During these extra sessions of preparation, she can fill these unused spell slots ... Like the first session of the day, this preparation takes at least 15 minutes, and it takes longer if she prepares more than one-quarter of his spells.

In summary:

- All spells = 1 hour
- Some spells = 15 minutes per 1/4 of your slot allotment