# When can you prepare a recently casted spell?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spell-slots, divine

The Pathfinder rules for divine spellcasting state that:

> at the time of preparation any spells cast within the previous 8 hours count against the number of spells that can be prepared.

But does that mean that you lose a spell slot for that day, or can you use an extra session of preparation to prepare a spell in that slot, once enough time has passed?

---

For example, my cleric got ambushed midnight and burned the 3rd-level domain slot. He can't prepare another 3-level domain spell on his preparation session on the morning, 4h after casting the spell.
 But can he prepare a spell un that slot with an extra session once the full 8h have elapsed, or must he wait until the *next* morning and preparation session?

Comment: Related: [Clerics and Spell Preparation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/13805/clerics-and-spell-preparation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means both, really. When you prepare spells, any spell slots you used in the past 8 hours cannot be used; you cannot prepare spells in them. Until you prepare spells again, they are empty.

However, [you are allowed to prepare spells multiple times in a day](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/#TOC-Preparing-Divine-Spells), if you have spell slots open to put them in.

> When preparing spells for the day, a divine spellcaster can leave some of her spell slots open. Later during that day, she can repeat the preparation process as often as she likes. During these extra sessions of preparation, she can fill these unused spell slots. She cannot, however, abandon a previously prepared spell to replace it with another one or fill a slot that is empty because she has cast a spell in the meantime. Like the first session of the day, this preparation takes at least 15 minutes, and it takes longer if she prepares more than one-quarter of his spells.

So once it has been 8 hours since you cast spells from those slots, you can stop and prepare spells again to fill those slots (the ones you originally prepared remain fixed, however). This feature can be very useful even outside of this circumstance, since you can purposefully leave some spell slots open to prepare later, in case you need something unusual. Preparing spells later in the day requires 15 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

### You may only prepare it again during your daily meditation

As described under **Spells** of the [Cleric](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/cleric/) class:

> A cleric may prepare and cast any spell on the cleric spell list, provided that she can cast spells of that level, but **she must choose which spells to prepare during her daily meditation**.

This means that, other than leaving spell slots open to prepare spells later (taking an hour to do so), she must pick a specific time of the day (usually related to her god, but not necessarily), and she may only prepare spell slots during that period of time (or as soon as possible), as explained under **Time of Day** under [Preparing Divine Spells](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/#TOC-Preparing-Divine-Spells):

> A divine spellcaster chooses and prepares spells ahead of time, but unlike a wizard, does not require a period of rest to prepare spells. Instead, the character chooses a particular time of day to pray and receive spells. The time is usually associated with some daily event. If some event prevents a character from praying at the proper time, she must do so as soon as possible. If the character does not stop to pray for spells at the first opportunity, she must wait until the next day to prepare spells.

Spells cast during the 8 hours before the daily meditation count against the total slot spells available to prepare new spells, as explained under [Recent Casting Limit/Rest Interruptions](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/#TOC-Preparing-Divine-Spells):

> If a wizard has cast spells recently, the drain on his resources reduces his capacity to prepare new spells. When he prepares spells for the coming day, all the spells he has cast within the last 8 hours count against his daily limit.
>
> As with arcane spells, at the time of preparation any spells cast within the previous 8 hours count against the number of spells that can be prepared.

While there are no developer comments confirming this, this is the interpretation that is mostly accepted by the community, as seen [here](https://paizo.com/threads/rzs2uhzy?Reason-for-recent-casting-limit#5), [here](https://paizo.com/threads/rzs2ppwf?Are-special-abilities-affected-by-the-recent#34), [here](https://paizo.com/threads/rzs2nod0&page=4?Casternoncaster-problem-OK-but-why#154), [here](https://paizo.com/threads/rzs2m62k?Cleric-spell-slots-and-arcane-spells#27), [here](https://paizo.com/threads/rzs2pwce?Per-Day-shenanigans#10), [here](https://paizo.com/threads/rzs2stdv?How-do-Psychic-classes-regain-spells-per-day#10), [here](https://paizo.com/threads/rzs2m3ys?How-do-spontaneous-casters-get-their-spell#47) and [so on](https://paizo.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/Store.woa/wa/search?q=recent%20casting%20limit&what=messageboards&sort=0&page=1).

Finally, *psychic* spellcasters make no mention of such rule, and one would assume that they have no limitation, but it has been [confirmed by Mark Seifter](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2r7kg&page=62?Ask-Mark-Seifter-All-Your-Questions-Here#3100) (Designer) that they also have a recent casting limit.

However, many people are fine with disregarding that rule, due to the complications it causes with spellcasters who prepare at a different time than right after a 8-hour rest (like clerics of Desna), or groups with characters who prepare their spells at different times, causing confusion at the table. As such, those people will (house rule) to completely refill their spell slots after a 8-hour rest, regardless if some spells were casting during the recent casting limit.

Comment: That I understand, but would a spell cast during the 8h previous to the daily meditation force me to leave an open slot, in which I can prepare a spell later on that day, or consume that slot for the entire day?

Comment: You can only leave open a spell slot that is available to be prepared. As the rules says "recently cast spells count against the limit". So those slots are no longer available for that day.

Comment: “You can only leave open a spell slot that is available to be prepared.” [Citation Needed] Your bolded quotation does not say that, if you are thinking that is your citation.

Comment: @KRyan I dont understand your comment. My answer barely touches that subject (quoting myself: " other than leaving spell slots open to prepare spells later"). The OP wasn't asking about that mechanic, but about taking another 8 hours of rest.

Comment: @ShadowKras The question is having cast a spell at time T, prepared spells for the day at T+4 (and having been unable to prepare anything in that spell slot at that time), can he prepare something in that slot at T+8. And the answer to that is yes, he can, because if you have any spell slots left open after preparing your spells for the day, you can put spells in those slots with 15 minutes of studying/praying. Except you seem to be claiming, without evidence, that these spell slots do not count as “left open” and cannot be used until the following day (T+24). Or your answer is very unclear.

Comment: @KRyan my answer is saying exactly that spells cast during the previous 8 hours of your daily meditation will leave that spell slot unusable until your next daily meditation, which is exactly what is said (and quoted here) on the rules. I fail to see where Im claiming anything without evidence.

Comment: If, during your 8-hours rest, you had an encounter and used a 3rd level spell slot, out of 4 slots available, by the morning you will only have 3 out of those 4 slots available to prepare new spells.

Comment: For reference, its the same thing being claimed on [this other answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/15326/21153) here on the site. I know this rule also existed in 3.5 and that it was quite unpopular, but it's in the rules. But since clerics may only prepare their spells once, I fail to see how that slot is left open to be used a few hours later like that wasnt even a problem to begin with (why this rule would even exist then?). Unless, of course, my answer is saying something different and I have failed to notice it so far.

Comment: You seem to be claiming that a spellcaster can prepare spells more than once in a day, which is clearly wrong (and can be evidenced by the text in the [ring of sustenance](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rings/ring-of-sustenance/)). They may only prepare spells later on those slots that they left open, but were available to have spells prepared on them. If a spell slot was not available during the daily preparation, that slot wont be available again until the next day.

Comment: The citations are all in the quoted rules. There is a "daily" limit, that means this limit is "per day", not "per preparation". I also quoted rules saying that **you only prepare once per day**. Honestly, looking at paizo messageboards, you are the only person that agrees that saying otherwise are the actual rules.

Comment: That citation is wrong, and it's what prompted the question in the first place. There is no _only_ in the rulebook, the line is "During these extra sessions of preparation, she can fill these unused spell slots.". And since the spell was not used that day, and is beyond the 8h "used" mark, I fail to see how it qualifies in any of the restrictions that would prevent me to prepare a spell in that slot. I'd say it should apply the same rules that would if a new spell slot were to be gained via other means, but I don't know the rules for that case either.

Comment: @RaulCastan you may only prepare spells a second time on spell slots that were left open during your **daily** preparation, I dont see how this isn't clear. Again, the ring of sustenance confirms that you only prepare once per day, regardless of how many times you rest.

Comment: “you may only prepare spells a second time on spell slots that were left open during your daily preparation, I dont see how this isn't clear,” it’s unclear because *nothing you have quoted actually says that.*

Comment: @KRyan Im not gonna argue back and forth with you on this subject, there are several threads like this at paizo.com and the answer (sadly, none from a developer) is always that you cannot prepare spells on spells used during the *recent casting limit* for the next day. My answer will remain as is, downvote and move on.